# Mobile browsers zoom in too much

Tags: zooming, mobile-browser

I'm building my first mobile website.

To ensure the site fills the screen appropriately I have set
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`

However, on my phone (Android 4.2.1) only Opera Mobile zooms in and fills the screen with the "viewport"-DIV. Chrome, Dolphin, Firefox and the Android Browser ALL zoom in a little bit too much, so a small part of the site is cut off on the right side of the screen, forcing horizontal scrolling.

I've spent the last hour trying different CSS settings and googling various combinations of "mobile browser zoom", but I haven't found a solution and it's driving me nuts.

To clarify: I want to have the browser zoom in just enough so the site fills the screen horizontally, NOT more.

I'm grateful for any help!